# MySQL ELSE returns zero as decimal instend of normal zero

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this query, else returns zero as decimal 0.00 instend of 0? I try insert player data into another table and calculate player accuracy at once. If accuracy calculate not possible when set zero in that column.

The query:

```
INSERT INTO player_tmp (id, name, accuracy) 
SELECT player.id, player.name,
CASE
    WHEN hit0 > 0 AND fired0 > 0 THEN ROUND(hit0/fired0,2)
    ELSE 0
END AS accuracy FROM player INNER JOIN weapons ON player.id = weapons.id ORDER BY weapons.kills0 DESC, accuracy DESC
```

Destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_tmp` (
  `pos` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(23) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `accuracy` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pos`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: What is the problem with it being decimal? (I hope you're not doing something like `value == "0"` in code.) If accuracy is always going to be numeric, why not define it as such? If you don't you'll have even more headaches down the line (when sorting gives this order `1,11,12,2,20,23,3`....)

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) of the `CASE` expression:

> The return type of a CASE expression is the compatible aggregated type of all return values

Meaning that the type of the `CASE` is always compatible to **all** possible values. `ROUND` returns decimal, hence `CASE` does so too.

I don't know what you were expecting. The results of a query must have **fixed type**, no matter what the data is.

Comment: should I use zero as string '0' ? Then working as I want.

Comment: @user3801788 that might work, or to make what you are doing clearer you could `CAST` both as `CHAR`